# Cloud Automation Manager Internal Service Error on IBM Cloud Private

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, cloud-automation-manager

I'm trying to install CAM through ICP, but I am constantly getting this error:

```
json error: 
Object { message: "Internal service error : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = 
release cam failed: Internal error occurred: admission webhook 
\"trust.hooks.securityenforcement.admission.cloud.ibm.com\" denied the 
request: \nDeny \"docker.io/store/ibmcorp/icam-bpd-cds:3.1.0.0-x86_64\", no 
matching repositories in ClusterImagePolicy and no ImagePolicies in the 
\"services\" namespace", statusCode: 500 }
reducerCatalogDetails.js:255:8
```

Does anyone know why this internal service error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a **imagepolicy.yaml** file:

```
apiVersion: securityenforcement.admission.cloud.ibm.com/v1beta1
kind: ImagePolicy
metadata:
  name: image-policy
spec:
  repositories:
  - name: "docker.io/store/ibmcorp/*"
    policy: null
```

and **kubectl apply -f imagepolicy.yaml -n services**

Comment: Thank you, Partha. When I try to apply the imagepolicy.yaml, I'm getting this issue:
error: unable to recognize "imagepolicy.yaml": Unauthorized

Comment: You may do it thru the UI: 
 **https://<master>:8443/console/manage/resourcesecurity/imagepolicies**
Create a new image-policy with scope services and add the 
docker.io/store/ibmcorp/*
to the repos list for this policy

Comment: Thanks Partha, I did that and got CAM helm deployed.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Container Image Security Enforcement - see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.1.0/manage_images/image_security.html for detailed explanation.

Can create or extend existing policies - ImagePolicy or ClusterImagePolicy depending on scope want allowed.   Note : ImagePolicy overrides ClusterImagePolicy for given namespace so be careful to include all want allowed.